# Distortion when using SpatialPolygons and SpatiaPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, rgeos

Using library rgeos I tried to plot a map using a shapefile I have (it is loaded as a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame) with some geometric objects (squares and circles defined as SpatialPolygons).

I do it like this:

```
plot(map)
plot(geometricObjects, add=True)
```

but as a result The geometric objects are disfigured and the circles look like ellipses. What is a reasonable way to fix this issue (plotting the objects first and adding the map results in the map being disfigured).

Comment: Oblate ellipses are the *correct* shape of spheriodal circles in decimal degrees. You'd need to choose a proper projection.